# I want to resolve an incorrect configuration error in the Google Speech To Text API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I get an error when making a request to Google Speech To Text.
I don't know the cause, can you help me solve it?

### error contents

```
3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding.. - {"trace":"Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..\n    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181)\n    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:117:74)\n    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:156:22)\n    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:142:18)\n    at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (/home/e-rex-api/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:274:14)\n    at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at ClientHttp2Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)"}
```

### Audio metadata used

I'm using ffmpeg.

```
{
   index: 0,
   codec_name: 'mp3',
   codec_long_name: 'MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)',
   profile: 'unknown',
   codec_type: 'audio',
   codec_time_base: '1/44100',
   codec_tag_string: '[0][0][0][0]',
   codec_tag: '0x0000',
   sample_fmt: 's16p',
   sample_rate: 44100,
   channels: 2,
   channel_layout: 'stereo',
   bits_per_sample: 0,
   id: 'N/A',
   r_frame_rate: '0/0',
   avg_frame_rate: '0/0',
   time_base: '1/14112000',
   start_pts: 0,
   start_time: 0,
   duration_ts: 81289912788,
   duration: 5760.339625,
   bit_rate: 192000,
   max_bit_rate: 'N/A',
   bits_per_raw_sample: 'N/A',
   nb_frames: 'N/A',
   nb_read_frames: 'N/A',
   nb_read_packets: 'N/A',
   disposition: {
     default: 0,
     dub: 0,
     original: 0,
     comment: 0,
     lyrics: 0,
     karaoke: 0,
     forced: 0,
     hearing_impaired: 0,
     visual_impaired: 0,
     clean_effects: 0,
     attached_pic: 0,
     timed_thumbnails: 0
   }
 }
```

### Settings sent in request

```
{
   languageCode: 'ja-JP',
   enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
   audioChannelCount: 2,
   sampleRateHertz: 44100,
   enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel: true,
   enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
   profanityFilter: true
 }
```

In another mp3 file, requests with the same settings are being processed successfully.
Is there a problem with the audio in this case?

The normal file has an encoder tag and the error file does not have an encoder tag.
`tags: { encoder: 'Lavc58.54' }`

What kind of solution is needed, whether the settings are insufficient or the audio needs to be processed?

Comment: The fact that mp3 codecs can be used is also stated in the documentation, and it has been confirmed that mp3 files are actually processed normally by the API.  
Among them, there was an mp3 file that caused an error, so I wanted to know how to solve it.  
My way of communicating was bad. I'm sorry.

Comment: ```
MP3 encoding is a Beta feature and only available in v1p1beta1. See the RecognitionConfig reference documentation for details.
```
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding

Answer (score 0):

According to [doccumentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/error-messages#invalid_recognition_config_bad_encoding), the "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding" message states that:

Your audio data might not be encoded correctly or is encoded with a codec different than what you've declared in the RecognitionConfig. Check the audio input and make sure that you've set the encoding field correctly.

Here is the [docummentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig) of the RecognitionConfig, please take a look so you can properly set the encoder for your audio file, some of the available [audio encodings](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#audioencoding) are:

- LINEAR16
- FLAC
- MULAW
- AMR
- AMR_WB
- OGG_OPUS
- SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE